# How to bulk insert with Spring-Batch?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm trying to do bulk/batch inserts using `spring-batch`.

```
public ItemWriter<MyEntity> jpaItemWriter() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(ds);
    builder.addAnnotatedClasses(MyEntity.class);
    builder.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    builder.setProperty("hibernate.batch_size", "20");
    builder.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
    builder.setProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
    HibernateItemWriter<MyEntity> writer = new HibernateItemWriter<>();
    writer.setSessionFactory(builder.buildSessionFactory());
    return writer;
}
```

Result:
I'm getting only single `insert` statements, not bulk inserts! I can see it from the logs both of hibernate + on postgresql level. Why is the bulk insert not working?

Update:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    String shortname;
    String fullname;
}
```

Comment: Can we see `MyEntity`?  Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if the primary key of the inserting table isGenerationType.Identity...

Comment: I don't have any insertion strategy on the ID as I control the ID's myself.

Comment: It would still be useful to see the `MyEntity` class.

Comment: Please see my update. Also: maybe I'm misinterpreting things, but: how would I actually identify "bulk inserts" in the sql log? All I see are plain insert statements one after the other, just as I would expect them to be seen without batch insert.

Comment: This really is a Hibernate question more than a Spring Batch question since the orchestration of a batch insert is handled by Hibernate, not Spring Batch.  Do you have autocommit = true on your datasource?

Comment: Can you not use the JdbcBatchItemWriter? http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html

Comment: Yes I can, but then I'd have to provide the SQL statements myself via an PrepatedStatement or similar, and explicit decide if it is update/insert statement. The advantage of `HibernateItemWriter` is it just does a `merge` automatically.

Comment: Spring Batch is a framework for multistepped processes, with functionality to repeat a failed process from the step it failed from, amongst other thing. Spring batch has nothing to do with database batch operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring has nothing to do with the SQL statements batching, its all managed by Hibernate. 
I see you have batching enabled and configured properly, but that's not enough to make it work...you also need to use the right session type. in hibernate there are two session types: **stateful** session and **stateless** session.
The **stateful** session, which is obtained with

```
sessionFactory.openSession();
```

and also is used by default if using @Transactional, never uses batching (even if configured) and sends all SQL statements, at once, at transaction commit. However, you can simulate batching by calling flush() from time to time, and SQL statements will be sent to the db on every flush().

The **stateless** session, which is obtained with

```
sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

respects the batching configuration, so just switch to **stateless** session, and batching will works as expected. Hibernate will log every session.insert(), but will not sent the SQL insert statement to the database, instead the SQL insert statements are sent as batches of configured size. So its best to "tail -f" the database log.
The main idea of having two session types is that, the **stateful** session uses cache, and every saved entity ends up in the 1st level cache, and therefore if you save 100k entities you will get OOM. The solution is to use **stateless** session which doesn't interact with any level cache.
You can read more about the [**stateless** session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html).